# leg pain near knee

Tags: pain

I have a leg pain just above knee (not knee pain), this happened after I pushed hard on bench press machine only my right and now I have right leg pain. is This normal or something like DVT?

pain is at two sides; I am sitting and looking my leg, at bottom left corner and right surface just near knee.

Comment: I voted to close as I think this should be taken to a doctor.

Comment: after watching dr.house's clinic mocking, I am picky on going doctors ^^

Comment: If you really avoid doctors because of a fictional drama enhanced character, you're in for trouble down the road.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at some basic anatomy charts, you'll see that's right where the *[rectus femoris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectus_femoris_muscle)* muscle and tendon attach. If the pain is mild, you're probably just a bit strained. Pull back a bit, do exercises that don't cause that area to hurt for a week or two, and see if it feels better. If the pain is sharp, or it's not getting better, see a doctor.

[image: Image from Wikipedia]